# Nginx try_files doesn't work 404, cannot load files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, static-files, nginx-config

I have been dealing with the problem for about several hours without any success. 
The problem that I cannot server static files from my project.

Previously I had the following rules for the **Apache server**.

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
```

I have tried the following location rules in my nginx configuration

```
  location ~ ^/css/?(.*)$ {
        #return 200 $document_root/web/css/$1;
        # kill cache
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
       #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
       try_files $document_root/web/css/$1 =404;
    }
```

By the way `#return 200 $document_root/web/css/$1;` returns the valid path.

But the request still fails.

Also I tried to use `alias` as follows

```
  location ~ ^/css/?(.*)$ {
        alias /var/wwww/myproject/web/css;
        # kill cache
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
    }
```

The same situation 404, if I change 404 in the location above it will also return another code, accordingly location statement is reached but try_files doesn't work

Please help to solve the issue, I don't know whatever to try.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your path to files can be constructed by concatenating the value of the `root` with the current URI, you should be using `root` and not `alias`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Assuming that `/css/foo.css` is physically located at `/var/www/myproject/web/css/foo.css` the following example should suffice.

```
location /css/ {
    root /var/www/myproject/web;
    ...
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

You do not need to use a regular expression `location` and you do not need to capture part of the URI.

The `try_files` statement needs to end with `=404` or `/index.php`, not both. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! It works however in order it to work I had to prepend the location path with `~`.
Could you explain why my variant doesn't work?

Comment: If you need to use a *regular expression* location, there may be another conflicting *regular expression* location block below - such as `location \.css`. You could use `location ^~ /css/` instead, which is still a prefix location but takes precedence over all regular expression locations. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.